# What Romanian surnames sound similar to Cashol?

Tags: surnames, romania, cyrillic

What Romanian surnames sound similar to Cashol and what would their spelling be in the cyrillic alphabet?

Specifically from the Buchovnia region.

Comment: Romanian is written in the Latin alphabet, and the region is Bukovina. (Greek Catholic and Greek Orthodox church records were sometimes written in variations on the Cyrillic alphabet, but they were in a Slavic language in that case, such as Ukrainian or Rusyn. Romanian is not a Slavic language.)

Comment: According to https://biblioteca-digitala.ro/reviste/carte/Instit-Lingvistica/dl.asp?filename=Boroianu_Texte-vechi-romanesti_1971.pdf until 1860s, manuscripts / books in various dialects of the Romanian language were often written / printed in Cyrillic script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't personally have experience researching in this area, but a very good friend of mine was raised in Romania.  She says that they don't use Cyrillic in Romania and wondered if you were thinking of Moldova or the Ukraine. It does appear that the region you're looking at has been passed back and forth.

She says that Cashol, though an unfamiliar name to her, would be spelled Cașol in Romanian (hope you can see the marking there under the s.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_alphabet).

She also gave me this link for a website on the distribution of Romanian family names:  http://nume.ottomotor.ro/en

Comment: Thank you for the information! I was off the mark on the cyrillic alphabet.